# change location of .sqlite_history file

Tags: environment-variables, home, sqlite

`sqlite3` stores command history in `.sqlite_history`, which is by default created in:

```
$HOME/.sqlite_history
```

How can I change this location to somewhere else?

This is possible for example with `mysql`, where I can define environment variable

```
MYSQL_HISTFILE=/path/to/whatever/file
```

But I could not find any corresponding environment variable for `sqlite3`

```
export SQLITE_HISTFILE=/tmp/history
```

has no effect. I found a [post](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Customizing-the-location-of-the-sqlite-history-td87055.html) where somebody asks same question, but no useful answers are given.

Comment: Request was made to the project at http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Customizing-the-location-of-the-sqlite-history-td87055.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Version 3.25.3 you can simply set SQLITE_HISTORY to change the history filename, like mattmc3 wrote. In the versions before, it was hardcoded in line 5576 in shell.c (version 3.14.1):

```
sqlite3_snprintf(nHistory, zHistory,"%s/.sqlite_history", zHome);
```

So, to change it, one option among the others mentioned in this thread <s>is</s> was to edit the source and recompile.

Comment: Be sure to check @mattmc3 answer as this is now possible.

Answer (score 3):

To list some of the possible alternatives,

1. make `~/.sqlite_history` into a symbolic link to another file.
2. simply run `HOME=/tmp sqlite3` to have the program save the history in `/tmp/.sqlite_history`, though this assumes you don't need the real home directory inside the command environment.
3. edit the binary and replace the string `"%s/.sqlite_history"`, found by Hoov, by another string with the same number of bytes, eg `"/tmp/sqlitehistory"`:

   ```
   sed < /usr/bin/sqlite3 's|%s/.sqlite_history|/tmp/sqlitehistory|' >/tmp/sqlite3
   cmp -l /usr/bin/sqlite3 /tmp/sqlite3 # check no extraneous differences
   chmod +x /tmp/sqlite3
   /tmp/sqlite3
   ```
4. use the `LD_PRELOAD` [shim](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237681/119298) I proposed in an another question to change one filename (`"/tmp/adb.log"` in that case) to another during an `open()` call.

Comment: Excellent and enlightening answer. I feel ignorant now.

Comment: But in reality, when this situation arises, I usually prefer to follow your answer and rebuild from sources, unless this proves to be too tedious, with too many dependencies etc.

Comment: Yes, it think it's the most manageable solution, but your solution three could come in handy when you don't have the source. Saved it to a script.

Comment: Note that in sqlite's case, setting `$HOME` will not work, since sqlite does not honour that environment variable: it uses only what `getpwuid()` returns (e.g. from `/etc/passwd`).

Answer (score 3):

As of Oct 10, 2018 [it appears that a new variable](https://www.sqlite.org/src/info/696e82f7c82d1720), `$SQLITE_HISTORY`, was added to address this.