# Is there a command that preloads `open()`, `fopen()`, etc. functions like `proxychains`?

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems, path

I learnt that we can use `LD_PRELOAD` to preload `open()` function to fake a path to a process.

I learnt it from here: [Is it possible to fake a specific path for a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/237636/is-it-possible-to-fake-a-specific-path-for-a-process)

I am wondering if there is a command, which redirects a process' reading/writing file to another path? Like `proxychains`, it uses LD_PRELOAD.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you write it yourself?

```
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int
open(const char *name, int flags, mode_t mode)
{
    int (*real_open)() = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open");

    if (strcmp(name, "xxzzy") == 0) {

          do my stuff
          .....
    }
    return (real_open(name, flang, mode);
}
```