# Arbitrary "files" in /proc/?

Tags: linux, proc, reverse-engineering

Is there a way to create files in `/proc/` without actually writing a kernel module?

This is for reverse engineering purposes, an app expects certain things in `/proc/` and I do not want to write a kernel module to supply it. The app simply just reads `/proc/something/some_key` and expects certain/known values.

EDIT: Union mount doesn't seem to work as I need a new directory, e.g. `/proc/new_dir/` and some files in there and making union on top of `/proc/` itself seems to break it.

Comment: Did you check if it is possible to mount an overlay on top of `/proc`?

Comment: Then don't mount procfs or any API filesystem on it

Comment: You can use LD_PRELOAD and a small C program to override open. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237681/49439

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I tried but it uses `openat` to open `/proc/something/some_key` and LD_PRELOAD cannot catch that, I assume that is not dynamically linked to use `openat`