# Changing the path opened by openat of a program using LD_PRELOAD

Tags: linux, glibc, dynamic-linking, dynamic-loading

I want to change a path that a program actually opens on filesystem for some paths. The reason is that I want to run a program in parallel, but that program uses `/tmp/somedir/` as its temporary directory and parallel instances run into conflicts.

I found this great answer to do just that: [Is it possible to fake a specific path for a process?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/237681/27719). Sadly, while this works for `cat` as advertised, it does not work for my program. I thought the cause is that the program uses C++ API.

To reproduce, I first made a very simple program that writes something in a file:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("test.log");
    std::string_view text{"hello world\n"};
    myfile.write(text.data(), text.size());
    return 0;
}
```

I then used `strace` and saw this at the end:

```
brk(NULL)                               = 0x558b5d5e3000
brk(0x558b5d604000)                     = 0x558b5d604000
futex(0x7f94e2e7e77c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "test.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
write(3, "hello world\n", 12)           = 12
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

So it looks like C api is called, but the function used is `openat`.

I also saw this for the C so library, this will be relevant later:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
```

So I implemented `openat` in addition to `open`, and this is the full program. For test purposes, instead of changing a path I just log it into a file.

```
/*
 * capture calls to a routine and replace with your code
 * g++ -Wall -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -lstdc++ -o fake_open_file.so fake_open_file.cpp
 * LD_PRELOAD=/home/myname/fake_open_file.so cat
 */
#define _FCNTL_H 1 /* hack for open() prototype */
#undef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE /* needed to get RTLD_NEXT defined in dlfcn.h */
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <mutex>
#include <fstream>
#include <string_view>
#include <iostream>


// for the test, I just log anything that was open into a new log file
struct open_reporter
{
    open_reporter() = default;
    void report_filename(std::string_view filename)
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{file_report_mutex};
        if(!is_open) {
            myfile.open("/home/myname/fileopen.log");
        }
        std::string tmp = std::string{filename} + "\n";
        myfile.write(tmp.data(), tmp.size());
    }
    std::ofstream myfile;
    std::mutex file_report_mutex;
    bool is_open = false;
};

static open_reporter reporter_;

extern "C" {
    int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode)
    {
        static int (*real_open)(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode) = nullptr;

        if (!real_open) {
            real_open = reinterpret_cast<decltype(real_open)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open"));
            char *error = dlerror();
            if (error != nullptr) {
                reporter_.report_filename("ERROR OCCURED!");
                reporter_.report_filename(error);
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        reporter_.report_filename(pathname);
        return real_open(pathname, flags, mode);
    }

    int openat(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode)
    {
        static int (*real_openat)(int dirfd, const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode) = nullptr;

        if (!real_openat) {
            real_openat = reinterpret_cast<decltype(real_openat)>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "openat"));
            char *error = dlerror();
            if (error != nullptr) {
                reporter_.report_filename("ERROR OCCURED!");
                reporter_.report_filename(error);
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        reporter_.report_filename(pathname);
        return real_openat(dirfd, pathname, flags, mode);
    }
}
```

This works with `cat` still, but not with my test program. Even if I change `open` and `openat` to return 0, while this breaks `cat` it does not have any effect on my test program. I also checked if the symbols are in my binary:

```
$ nm -gD fake_open_file.so | grep open
0000000000001470 W _ZN13open_reporterD1Ev
0000000000001470 W _ZN13open_reporterD2Ev
0000000000001450 T open
0000000000001460 T openat
```

I can see both the functions present. Looking into C library, I see a difference, but I don't know what it means. I redacted things that are not `open` or `openat`:

```
$ nm -gD /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 |grep open
0000000000114820 W openat@@GLIBC_2.4
0000000000114820 W openat64@@GLIBC_2.4

0000000000114690 W open@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000114690 W open64@@GLIBC_2.2.5

0000000000114690 W __open@@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000114690 W __open64@@GLIBC_2.2.5
00000000001147c0 T __open64_2@@GLIBC_2.7
0000000000119b80 T __open64_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
0000000000114660 T __open_2@@GLIBC_2.7
0000000000040800 T __open_catalog@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
0000000000119b80 T __open_nocancel@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
0000000000114950 T __openat64_2@@GLIBC_2.7
00000000001147f0 T __openat_2@@GLIBC_2.7
```

Apart of the `@@GLIBC` stuff, these are the same. I never have done this before, so this is as far as my debugging ability goes. I am asking here and not SO because here is where I got the original answer and also this looks more like linux knowledge than a programming problem, the program itself is very simple.

Comment: "Probably the cause is that the program uses C++ API." no, all C++ runtimes I'm aware of use standard libc calls underneath

Comment: @MarcusMüller yes, correct. I should've written "I thought probably...". `strace` proved this idea wrong, as it logs `openat` C function.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Turns out my suspicion was correct in the end, check the answer. This is unfortunate, as it makes the whole task much more difficult.

Comment: @TomášZato Have you tried limiting the calls that `strace` monitors to a small list, say open, open64, stat, write, close?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Background: C

Your `strace` output shows...

```
brk(NULL)                               = 0x558b5d5e3000
brk(0x558b5d604000)                     = 0x558b5d604000
futex(0x7f94e2e7e77c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "test.log", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666) = 3
write(3, "hello world\n", 12)           = 12
close(3)                                = 0
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

...but `strace` traces system calls, not function calls...and function interposition via `LD_PRELOAD` works with *function* calls. With a C program, the `openat` call is likely being called via `open` or `open64`. So for example, if I start something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    int fd;
    int nb;

    if (-1 == (fd = open("test.log", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666))) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (-1 == (nb = write(fd, "hello world\n", 12))) {
        perror("write");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("write %d bytes\n", nb);

    return 0;
}
```

I see in the `strace` output that this calls:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "test.log", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0666) = 3
```

But if I attempt to override `openat` with `LD_PRELOAD`, as you have, I see the same behavior: it doesn't work. However, if I intercept the `open` call instead:

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode) {
    static int (*real_open)(const char *, int, mode_t);

    fprintf(stderr, "OPEN PATH: %s\n", pathname);

    if (!real_open) {
        real_open = (dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "open"));
        char *error = dlerror();
        if (error != NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "ERROR OCCURED! %s\n", error);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return real_open(pathname, flags, mode);
}
```

Then it works great:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./fakeopen.so ./c_example
OPEN PATH: test.log
write 12 bytes
```

### More complicated: C++

Things are a little more complicated with C++ code, because when you write...

```
myfile.open("test.log");
```

...what exactly is getting called?  If we look at the output of `LD_DEBUG=symbols ./your_program`, we see things like:

```
    420239:     symbol=_ZNSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4openEPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode;  lookup in file=./cc_main [0]
    420239:     symbol=_ZNSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4openEPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode;  lookup in file=/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0]
```

So the actual function call is to a [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) name like `_ZNSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4openEPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode`. We can override that just like any other function. If we create `wrapper.cc` with:

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
    int _ZNSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4openEPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode() {
        {
            std::cerr << "This is the wrapped open method\n";
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And compile this to `wrapper.so`:

```
g++ -shared -fPIC -o wrapper.so wrapper.cc
```

Then we can use it with your simple program:

```
LD_PRELOAD=./wrapper.so ./your_program
```

And get as output:

```
$ LD_PRELOAD=./wrapper.so ./your_program
This is the wrapped open method
```

So there, we have successfully wrapped the `open` method! To get it to successfully call the real method, you would need to figure out what the function signature for `_ZNSt14basic_ofstreamIcSt11char_traitsIcEE4openEPKcSt13_Ios_Openmode` actually looks like. I'm not a C++ person, and I can't answer that question, but hopefully this helps you make forward progress.

### Misc notes

It may be possible to perform the function overloading using C++, which would allow you to use regular function names rather than mangled names (and you woudn't need to deal with guessing what the C prototype looks like for a C++ function).

That is discussed a little bit in [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410990/ld-preload-for-c-class-methods).

Comment: So... in the and I was right when I suspected that C++ api is different call alltogether. Thanks a lot for the analysis. I'll see if I can get it to work the C++ way, but if not I might just use the mangled names that I find in the real binary I need to spoof folders for.